# How to connect the USB Cable of a techole HDMI splitter to linux?

Tags: linux, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm talking about this device: https://www.amazon.de/Techole-Aluminium-Verteiler-Unterst%C3%BCtzt-Blu-Ray-Player-Schwarz/dp/B07DW2445X/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&keywords=hdmi+usb+splitter&qid=1566994078&s=gateway&sr=8-5

It's an HDMI splitter that includes an USB input. Connecting the HDMI input to the PC works, but connecting the USB input doesn't. (And that's what I need to use extended monitors, rather then simply duplicating the monitor.=

Comment: "connecting the USB input doesn't." - Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't read German, so I found the same thing on [Amazon UK](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Splitter-Techole-Aluminum-Supports-Projector-Black/dp/B07DW2445X/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_504_img_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=DQ3A7DMJ7W22BCQYW3HT), which says…

> Just connect your HDMI devices via Techole HDMI splitter and the USB charger cable with standard 5V adapter for extra power supply (USB adapter not provided)*

So it sounds like you need an external power supply for it.

*<sub>That's verbatim - still sounds like it was google translated from Chinese.</sub>